# SSIS split execution path based on variables

Tags: ssis

I am quite new to SSIS. Currently I have a package where the first step is a Data Flow task that returns a list of "ProcessId" and a set of "Jobs To Do" (JobsToDo can be "Authorize", "Notify", "Execute Process", etc).

Then I have a ForEach Loop Container that loops thought these and sets the ToDo boolean flags (variables) of what should be done for the current "Process".

How do I validate logically against these variables and split the execution path, considering that multiple paths can be executed (eg. "Authorize" and "Notify")?

I hope the question makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

You do this in the precedence constraints.   After you use the arrows to connect one task to another, double click on the line between the two tasks and you can edit the conditions under which a task will go from one to the next.

You can add an expression that checks the value of a variable.   If the condition evaluates to `true` then it will go to that next step.   If `false` it will not.

Comment: It does make sense, but inside the ForEach container I currently only have standalone tasks like "Notify" and "Authorize" - that should be triggered based on the "ToDo" variables. There are no arrows or connections that I can create conditions upon. So I could I possibly do that?

Comment: In the ForEach container, add a script task that does nothing as a "dummy" task to use as a starting point.   Then add the arrows from the script task to the other tasks that you want to only trigger conditionally.